# Can't connect to hostapd hotspot - Password Loop

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, android, hostapd

I have a Linksys router that I've set to use `Mixed B/G Mode`, `WPA2 Personal`, and `AES`, and I'm trying to replicate that setup on a single-board computer running `hostapd` so that I can eliminate a box from a portable system that I'm building.  (that computer has other functions as well, so it can't go away)

My Windows 7 laptop seems to be okay with the `hostapd`-based network - in fact, I'm using it right now to post this - but the Lubuntu laptop that's going to be part of this portable system repeatedly asks for the password and never connects while my Android phone seems to hang after taking the password and doesn't connect either.

All three devices connect to the Linksys router without any problems, so I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`.  Here it is:

```
interface=wlan2
driver=nl80211
ssid=My-Hotspot
hw_mode=g
channel=8
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
ieee80211n=1
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=AGoodPassw0rd
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK WPA-EAP WPA-PSK-SHA256 WPA-EAP-SHA256
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

(ssid and passphrase changed for security, and comments removed for code readability)

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little bit more research got me [here](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot), which is one of many sites that offer different default configurations.  But this one happened to work.  Windows, Lubuntu, and Android all connect to this one without a problem:

```
interface=wlan2
driver=nl80211
ssid=My-Hotspot
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=AGoodPassw0rd
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

And here's the difference:

[image]

The "No" header has the problem described in the question.  The "Yes" header works.